# jQuery Responsive Menu removing CSS backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

For some reason whenever you click the last sub-menu drop down button on "Contact", it causes all the menu li backgrounds to disappear. Anyone have any idea what's going on. This is so weird.

The website is http://morevent.alliancemediahouston.com

and the responsive menu will come up when your screen is resized passed 768px.

Thanks for your help.

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){

 $("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").addClass("responsive-menu").before('<div class="responsive-menu-icon"></div>');

 $(".responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){
  $(this).next("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu").slideToggle();
 });

 $(window).resize(function(){
  if(window.innerWidth > 768) {
   $("header .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, nav .sub-menu").removeAttr("style");
   $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").removeClass("menu-open");
  }
 });

 $(".responsive-menu > .menu-item").click(function(event){
  if (event.target !== this)
  return;
   $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").slideToggle(function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass("menu-open");
  });
 });

});
```

Comment: Add the code here, instead of giving website link

Comment: I added the jQuery code I'm using.

Comment: It looks like if I add a height to the ul it sort of fixes the problem. But now, the very last sub-menu still has a z-index no matter what I do.

Comment: Also, the menu starts as open instead of closed.

Answer (score 0):

remove this class from last menu li tag

```
menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1771 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-1773
```

to

```
current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children
```

Comment: I don't see those classes on the last menu li tag?

Comment: the last menu <li> contains this class please remove it. and give class class name which previous contains.

Comment: The last li has none of those classes except for "menu-item-has-children".